# Mongoose not returning correct results when querying MongoDB using variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a MongoDB query to work with a variable that takes inputs.

This is an example of the query that I want. And when it is created this way it returns the correct results.

```
var type = 'Math';
var query = User.find({'serviceInterests': type,'availability.Friday.2a':'false'});
```

When I create it that way, it doesn't produce any results:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes()/60;
if(min >= .5){
    hour++;
}
if(hour > 12){
    hour = `${hour - 12}p`
} else {
    hour = `${hour}a`
}
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
var type = 'Math';
var time = `${hour-12}-${hour -11}`;
var avail = `'availability.${days[5]}.${hour}'`

var connection = mongoose.connect(config.database);
var query = User.find({'serviceInterests': type, avail: 'false'});
```

Comment: Have you tried using ES6 computed property key syntax `var query = User.find({'serviceInterests': type, [avail]: 'false' });`?

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb, using the ES6 key syntax fixed this.

```
 var query = User.find({'serviceInterests': type, [avail]: 'false' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
var params = {};
params[avail] = 'false';
params['serviceInterests'] = type;

var query = User.find(params);
```